# Heard that "master of something" is pronounced as 'shokaneen'—could you help me find the right term?

Tags: spelling

I attended a talk at SXSW and the chef Paul Qui had a great quote but I don't know how to spell the work in English (and Japanese) and could use some help. Here is the quote, with the best attempt at the word as I could manage.

> I don't know what that dream project is and I am always in search of that dream project. In Japanese there's a term called ***shokaneen*** that means to be the master of something, but nobody is ever ***shokaneen*** you're always to trying to chase (that) to be a master in whatever that is. For me, whatever that dream is—and I don’t know what it is—I keep on chasing it.

Comment: Best guess I can make is that you heard either 職人 (*shokunin*, lit. workman or artisan) or 商売人 (*shoubainin*, lit. merchant or expert in a given trade).

Comment: 職人 is definitely to what that's pointing: "a true craftsman" or "true artisan"

Comment: By the way, it is pronounced "show- koo- neen" and has roughly the same meter as the english word "magazine"

Comment: @Eric maybe post 職人 as an answer?

Answer (score 3):

Since I'm guessing you're intending the *ee* sound as approximately that of "between", that's represented by *i* in romaji, making the end *nin*, which refers to people, appropriately enough.

However, I couldn't think of (or find) any word *shokanin* or *shoukanin*, or even *shokkanin*, so I had to take a few liberties.

I think the word you most likely heard is actually [職人](http://www.romajidesu.com/dictionary/meaning-of-%E8%81%B7%E4%BA%BA.html) (*shokunin*, lit. workman or artisan). It doesn't precisely mean "master" by any stretch, but it fits the idea of always working hard to perfect one's craft.

<sub>(Note: Converted from a comment in lieu of other answers.)</sub>

Comment: +1 because answering unanswered questions is good and healthy for this site. And now that I think about it, the u in shok**u**nin is sometimes devoiced/barely audible; and in English the a in shok**a**neen could sound like a *schwa* (as in prob**a**bility). So I think the intended sound of *shokaneen* might actually be quite close to 職人 (as it sounds to an English speaker).